# Как эффективно получить несколько минимальных значений из коллекции?

Tags: kotlin

Как эффективно получить несколько минимальных значений из коллекции?

Есть ли другие способы, кроме `collectionOrSequence.sortedby{it.value}.take(n)`?

Меня смущает то, что `sortedby` по сути создает новую полную коллекцию. Хотя достаточно было бы создать новую коллекцию только для n элементов.

Answer (score 0):

`Sequences` же как раз для этого придуманы. Ленивые коллекции, вычисляется только то, к чему обращаешься.

> Sequence type that represents lazily evaluated collections.

Отсюда:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/index.html

Так что `collectionOrSequence` в вопросе не совсем корректная формулировка, они ведут себя по-разному.

Comment: :) согласен. так должно быть в общем случае. однако в данном конкретном случае это не так. разница проявляется только для take и find. для sort - никакой разницы. sequence - это первое, что я проверил :)